# How to setup embedded linux as Bluetooth SPP server?

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, bluez

Now I'm trying to make embedded Linux system act as Bluetooth SPP server. 
In the system, blueZ can be used and I've already checked `bluetoothctl` command is enabled to scan, pair and connect with some bluetooth devices (iPhone and mac book).

However, in spite of searches, there is no information to make Linux as Bluetooth SPP server with automatically paring and connection. I'm trying to realize the use case below:

(1) Some setups on the Linux system (enabling bluetooth daemon, hcitool, SPP server, and so on...)
(2) The client device scans the Bluetooth (Linux). If found, it tries to pair.
(3) When pairing request received, the Linux system will pair the client device.
(4) The client device tries to connect the Linux system. 
(5) The Linux system allows to connection.

I want to know whether or not this use case is realizable, and if possible, I'd like to know some tutorials or sample codes. 
The best case is that I can realize the use case above with C (or C++) programming using BlueZ (dBus API).

Comment: Did you already checked this repo https://github.com/tonyespy/bluez5-spp-example ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. It seems to be suitable for my use.

One thing I have to know is that in the example, whether the client Linux device should be prepared or not. 
In my case, the client device is the general terminal (Android or iOS smartphone/tablet). 
For example, if you prepared the mac book and iPhone, you can request pairing and connection from iPhone to mac book via Bluetooth (the Bluetooth menu in the setting application on iPhone). The embedded system will alternate the mac book in analogy.

Comment: This repo doesn't have any functionality implemented for pairing and connection. It specifically takes care of SPP only (still old code). You need to fix up many things in that repo. For pairing and connection, you can refer the examples in https://gist.github.com/parthitce and explanation for these examples in https://www.linumiz.com/category/blog/